# confused about return array#map javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming

I have the code:

```
function func1(){
  return 
    array.map(function(el){
      return el.method();
    });
}

function func2(){
  var confused = 
    array.map(function(el){
      return el.method();
    });
  return confused;
}
```

Why `func1` return `undefined` while `func2` return good value (that i need)?

Sorry for my english.

Comment: Automatic semicolon insertion.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Internally in JS engine first example looks like this,

```
function func1() {
  return;
    array.map(function(el){
      return el.method();
    });
};
```

that's why you get `undefined`, don't add new line after `return`, because return statement followed by a new line tells the JS intepreter that a semi colon should be inserted after that return.

```
function func1() {
  return array.map(function(el){
     return el.method();
  });
};
```